# problem of alignement in a table with a pmatrix inside a multirow

Tags: multirow, multicolumn

Here is the simple code

```
\begin{tabular}{cccl}
a            & b            & c           &       \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &0&0,25 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0,25&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$}} & dgf   \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{}                      & dgfhb \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{}                      & dghb 
\end{tabular}
```

And as you can see, the "a", "b", and "c" are not center aligned. But if I remove the `pmatrix` inside the `multirow`, all works fine.
Do you have an explanation, and know how to solve that? That is, I would like the "a" above the first column of the matrix, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `blkarray` package is what you're after. Instead of the `pmatrix`, you can use a `block` with the `()` delimiters. As per @Bernard's comment, you can add two `\bigstrut`s to enlarge the parentheses a bit. See the following `blkarray` and how it compares to the `pmatrix` of `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blkarray,bigstrut}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{blockarray}{cccl}
a & b & c & \\
\begin{block}{(ccc)l}
  1    & 0 & 0.25 & \text{dgf}   \bigstrut[t]\\
  0    & 1 & 0    & \text{dgfhb}             \\
  0.25 & 0 & 1    & \text{dghb}  \bigstrut[b]\\
\end{block}
\end{blockarray}
\]
% Compared to amsmath's pmatrix:
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &0&0,25 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0,25&0&1 \end{pmatrix}\text{dgfhb}
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: You should use `\bigstrut` for  a better size of the parentheses.

Comment: @abo Actually I wanted to avoid `blockarray` because the parentheses are a little bit different than the one used by `amsmath`, and since I use matrices several in my document, it is for a coherence. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @Bernard Could you tell more about that `\bigstrut`? Does it make look like the parentheses of `amsmath` package?

Comment: And anyone knows why my code doesn't give the right output ?

Comment: @antoine: The parentheses (or the brackets) are a bit short with blkarray. To have them less short, you can add  `\bigstrut[t] ` (from the homonymous package that comes with `multirow`) on the first line, and `\bigstrut[b]` on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use the amsmath `*matrix`  environments, you can do it with the `gauss` and `pgffor`  packages. I perverted it to define an `annotmatrix`   (‘annotated matrix’)  environment. It accepts an optional argument for the delimiter, like the `gmatrix` from `gauss`.

Annotations for columns have to be coded inside the environment after the directive `\colops` with the command `\matlab{column index}{label}`. Similarly  annotations for row  are introduced with `\rowops` and coded with the same command `\matlab{row index}{label}`. Note the row and column indices start at $0$.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{gauss, pgffor}

\def\matlab{\mult}
\newenvironment{annotmatrix}[1][]{%
\let\rowmultlabel\text \let\colmultlabel\text\setlength{\rowarrowsep}{2pt}\setlength{\colarrowsep}{1.5ex}%
\gmatrix[#1]}
{\endgmatrix}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{annotmatrix}[p]
    1 &0&0{,}25 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0{,}25&0&1
     \colops
     \foreach \i/\lab in {0/a, 1/b, 2/c}{\matlab{\i}{\footnotesize\lab}}
     \rowops
     \foreach \i/\lab in {0/dgf, 1/dgfhb, 2/dghb}{\matlab{\i}{\footnotesize\lab}}
  \end{annotmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]